# python sage attach from command line and run another command

Tags: command-line, sage

I want to load a sage file and run a function from that file, all from bash.

The `attach` command is giving me trouble...

This works:

```
bash-prompt$ sage -c "print 2; print 3"
2
3
bash-prompt$
```

This also works:

```
bash-prompt$ sage -c "attach somefile.sage"
some print just to confirm the file is loaded
bash-prompt$
```

But this doesn't work:

```
bash-prompt$ sage -c "attach somefile.sage; print 3"
python: can't open file '/path/to/somefile.sage; print Integer(3)': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I get this to work, or what can I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is to call the function as the last line in the actual Sage file: that is, "somefile.sage" will have as its last line `print 3`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps someone...

I ended up using this monstrosity:

```
sage somefile.sage && sage -python -c "execfile('somefile.py'); wrapper()" && rm somefile.py
```

Ok, the `rm` part is not really all that necessary :)